# How can i give clearfix for responsive design in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When adding extra contents, grid becomes ugly so i gave clearfix after every 3rd child in jquery like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#clearallcat > div:nth-child(3n)").after("<div class='clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block'></div>");
    </script>
```

so that it correctly used clearfix after every 3rd tag and it fits for medium and large desktops

http://s9.postimg.org/xhw81689b/clearfix_doubt.png

but when im trying to add for tablet size , script not working .. here i tried is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#clearallcat > div:nth-child(3n)").after("<div class='clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block'></div>");
    $("#clearallcat > div:nth-child(2n)").after("<div class='clearfix visible-sm-block'></div>");
    </script>
```

this is the image in tablet view
[image]

what should i change in jquery to retify tablet fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, your each block has a **.board-item** class, then write some css like this for diffrent viewports:

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    .board-item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear:left //every 3rd element falls in new row
    }
}
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1200px) {
  .board-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
   clear:left //every 4th element falls in new row
  }
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .board-item:nth-child(4n+1) {
   clear:left //every 5th element falls in new row
  } 
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the first min-width otherwise, depending on tile size, you'll have a mess again. 

Also your nth-child calcs work but are a little odd. e.g. 4n-7 will match the -7th and -3rd children (which cannot exist) and then 1st, 5th and 9nth and so on but 4n+1 will match the 1st, 5th, 9th etc and to my mind is much clearer. Similarly the first two could be replaced with 2n+1 and 3n+1

Comment: @Deepak Thanks a lot .. it works great ...will update if any further issues when it goes live.